# Python datetime not including DST when using pytz timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc, pytz

If I convert a UTC datetime to swedish format, summertime is included (CEST). However, while creating a datetime with sweden as the timezone, it gets CET instead of CEST. Why is this?

```
>>> # Modified for readability
>>> import pytz
>>> import datetime
>>> sweden = pytz.timezone('Europe/Stockholm')
>>>
>>> datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 20, 16, 20, tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(sweden)
datetime(2010, 4, 20, 18, 20, tzinfo=<... 'Europe/Stockholm' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
>>> 
>>> datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 20, 18, 20, tzinfo=sweden)
datetime(2010, 4, 20, 18, 20, tzinfo=<... 'Europe/Stockholm' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
>>>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `sweden` object specifies the CET time zone by default but contains enough information to know when CEST starts and stop.

In the first example, you create a `datetime` object and convert it to local time.  The `sweden` object knows that the UTC time you passed occurs during daylight savings time and can convert it appropriately.

In the second example, the `datetime` constructor always interprets your input as not-daylight-savings-time and returns an appropriate object.

If `datetime` treated your input as wall-clock time and chose the appropriate daylight-savings setting for you, there would be an ambiguity during the time of year when clocks are set back.  On a wall-clock the same hour occurs twice.  Hence, `datetime` forces you to specify which timezone you're using when you create the `datetime` object.

Comment: thanks for the info! Also, the localize function of a pytz.timezone object can be used to build the localized datetime, instead of datetime(..., tzinfo=<tz>)

Comment: @Jesper: [pytz docs](http://pytz.sf.net) explicitly say to use .localize() instead of datetime constructor with tzinfo parameter for timezone with DST.

Answer (score 0):

Timezone abbreviations are not unique. For example "IST" could refer to "Irish Standard Time", "Iranian Standard Time", "Indian Standard Time" or "Isreali Standard Time". You shouldn't rely on parsing that, and instead should use zoneinfo timezones.