# Is datetime.replace fundamentally broken?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz, python-dateutil

Converting a timezone naive date time to a specific timezone gives a completely incorrect result.

```
import dateutil as du
import pytz    
du.parser.parse('2017-05-31T15:00:00').replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/London')).isoformat()
```

returns a one minute not one hour offset vs UTC

```
'2017-05-31T15:00:00-00:01'
```

I've seen a few datetime peculiarities before but this one is breathtaking.

Comment: Not quite sure why that warranted an immediate down vote with no comment.

Comment: what's dateutil (3rd party library, not in standard lib like datetime)? what's the result after `parse`?

Comment: Its a fairly well know [package](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).  Parse produces a standard datetime object.

Comment: Can you add the output of `parse` to the question? It will be helpful to see where the problem is.

Comment: I wouldn't say `datetime.replace` is fundamentally broken. It's [well documented](http://pythonhosted.org/pytz/) that pytz does not exactly adhere to the `tzinfo` API specified in the Python documentation, and that using a pytz time zone object as the `datetime.tzinfo` parameter is unreliable.

Comment: Either use a tzinfo compliant time zone interface like `dateutil.tz` or use `pytz.timezone("Europe/London").localize(my_datetime)`.

Comment: This is a [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631578/python-datetime-pytz-issue), [very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659908/python-datetime-not-including-dst-when-using-pytz-timezone) [common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856643/unexpected-results-converting-timezones-in-python) [misunderstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410971/python-datetime-object-show-wrong-timezone-offset). (Some would argue those are all duplicate questions, and there are probably plenty more.)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem here is that you are using a `pytz` time zone. `pytz` zones do not follow the `tzinfo` interface and cannot be simply attached to `datetime` objects (either through the constructor or through `replace`). If you would like to use `pytz` time zones, you should use [`pytz.timezone.localize`](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) with a naive `datetime`. If the `datetime` is already timezone-aware, you can use [`datetime.astimezone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) to convert it between zones.

```
from dateutil import parser
import pytz

LON = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
dt = parser.parse('2017-05-31T15:00:00')
dt = LON.localize(dt) 

print(dt)   # 2017-05-31 15:00:00+01:00
```

This is because `pytz`'s interface uses `localize` to attach a static time zone to a `datetime`. For the same reason, if you do arithmetic on the now-localized `datetime` object, it may give similar improper results and you'll have to use `pytz.timezone.normalize` to fix it. The reason this is done this way is that, historically, it has not been possible to handle ambiguous datetimes using a Pythonic `tzinfo` interface, which changed with [PEP 495](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0495/) in Python 3.6, making `pytz`'s workaround less necessary.

If you would like to pass a `tzinfo` to a `datetime` using `replace` or the constructor, or you would prefer to use the pythonic interface, `dateutil`'s time zone suite implements a PEP 495-compliant `tzinfo` interface. The equivalent using a [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html) zone is:

```
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil import tz

LON = tz.gettz('Europe/London')
dt = parser.parse('2017-05-31T15:00:00').replace(tzinfo=LON)

print(dt)   # 2017-05-31 15:00:00+01:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I have often had bad luck using [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) with [`tzinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) objects.  I have however found this construct to be reliable:

#### Code:

```
def naive_to_aware(ts, tz):
    return tz.localize(ts)
```

#### Update from Comments:

From the ([pytz DOCS](http://pythonhosted.org/pytz/))

> Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones.
>
> It is safe for timezones without daylight saving transitions though, such as UTC

So it is not just *bad luck*, it is problematic for pytz objects with timezones having DST.

#### Test Code:

```
import dateutil as du
import pytz

print(naive_to_aware(du.parser.parse('2017-05-31T15:00:00'),
                     pytz.timezone('Europe/London')).isoformat())
```

#### Results:

```
2017-05-31T15:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: It's not "bad luck". The pytz documentation states, close to the beginning: *This library differs from the documented Python API for tzinfo implementations*. It goes on to state that one way to use pytz time zones is with the `astimezone` method, and that you should specifically avoid using it as the `tzinfo` argument if it has daylight saving transitions. It explicitly says UTC is safe for `tzinfo`. So, it seems you have basically discovered for yourself what the pytz documentation recommends. ;)

Comment: @JohnY, thank you so much for that info.  An incompatible API would certainly explain why I just thought it was luck...  Updated to reflect the *why*.

Comment: @StephenRauch Your first bit of code does something completely different than `.replace(tzinfo=tz)`. `replace` just attaches the `tzinfo` without modifying the time. Your code assumes that the code is already in UTC. This will give the wrong answer if you have a naive `datetime` representing, e.g. Eastern Time and you simply want to attach a zone to it.

Comment: Note, I downvoted because this is wrong and misleading. I'm happy to retract if/when it's edited.